# Converting Javascript to Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

How to change this javascript to coffeescript?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash;
    var $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 900, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
});
});
```

I tried this code in my rails project,but it doesn't work

```
$(document).on 'page:change', ->
$('a[href^="#"]').click (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()

    target = this.hash
    $target = $(target）

    $('html, body').stop().animate{
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 900,
     'swing', ->
        window.location.hash = target
```

Do I have something wrong?

Comment: Simply use http://js2.coffee/ to convert javascript to coffee?

Comment: @HieuPham Post it as an answer.

Comment: Offhand, it looks like you're missing the `return` statements at the end of each block. But yes, online JS to CoffeeScript converters are your friend.

Comment: TIL CoffeeScript still exists.

Comment: @MarsAtomic in coffee you can skip return because CoffeeScript returns the last line. The mistake in the 2nd line, because author lost a whitespace and code looks like `$(document).on('page:change', function() {}); // ..` instead `$(document).on('page:change', function() { //.. `. Second mistake is here `animate{` - lost whitespace again. Remember that сoffee uses significant whitespace to delimit blocks of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work:

```coffee
$(document).ready ()=>
  $('a[href^="#"]').on 'click', (e)=>
    e.preventDefault()
    target = @hash
    $target = $(target)
    $('html, body').stop().animate scrollTop:$target.offset().top, 900, 'swing', ()=>
      window.location.hash = target
```

You asked if you've did something wrong, so here's a couple of things to keep in mind (sorry if this is obvious to you already):

1. The first line of your CoffeeScript version is completely different than the JavaScript version.  (`document.ready` vs. `document.on('page-change')`)
2. CoffeeScript is whitespace-sensitive.  I don't know if its just the StackOverflow formatting or in your actual code, but without leading spaces in your second line, the callback passed to `$(document).on 'page:change', ->` is a no-op.  In other words, the Javascript version would be `$(document).on('page:change', function(){});`
3. Similarly, the spaces that indent lines 9 (the one that starts with `'scrollTop'`) and 11 (the one that starts with `'swing'`) are likely to cause problems also.